# Unzipping multiple .gz files into single text file using Python

Tags: python, gzip

I am trying to unzip multiple .gz extentions files into single .txt file. All these files have json data.

I tried the following code:

```
from glob import glob
import gzip

for fname in glob('.../2020-04/*gz'):
    with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as f_in:
     with open('.../datafiles/202004_twitter/decompressed.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

But the decompressed.txt file only has the last .gz file's data.

Comment: Opening in `wb` mode erases the file first

Comment: Open the `txt` file *before* looping over the `gz` file list.  Then _append_ the data to the already opened `txt`.

Comment: Which mode should I use then?

Comment: Just stop re-opening the file over and over. Open it only once _outside_ the loop. `wb` is fine if you don't put the open inside the loop.

Comment: That is to say, put the `with open(...) as f_out:` on the _outside_, and the `for fname in ...:` inside it.

Comment: Your current code is wrong in the exact same way as the shell script `for fname in .../2020-04/*.gz; do gunzip -c <"$fname" >decompressed.txt; done` is. In shell, you would fix that by rewriting it to `for fname in .../2020-04/*.gz; do gunzip -c <"$fname"; done >decompressed.txt`, putting the `>decompressed.txt` _outside_ the loop instead of inside it. The Python equivalent to that is moving the `with open(...) as f_out:` to the outside.

Comment: Concatenating multiple json files will result in an invalid json file. Wouldn't it be better to load the json data for each file; put all the objects in a list; and then dump the list to a single json file?

Comment: @ekhumoro, ...that assumes it's actually JSON as opposed to JSONL.

Comment: How can I use json.dump here rather than shutil to load JSON data in the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shuffle `f_out` to the outside, so you open it *before* iterating over the input files and keep that one handle open.

```
from glob import glob
import gzip

with open('.../datafiles/202004_twitter/decompressed.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    for fname in glob('.../2020-04/*gz'):
        with gzip.open(fname, 'rb') as f_in:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `"wba"` mode instead. `a` opens in append mode. `w` alone will erase the file upon opening.

Comment: Please don't. This means multiple runs will append to each other (run the script twice and your `decompressed.txt` has two copies of each input document), and keeping the `open()` operation at the inner position in the loop is also far less efficient than opening the file only once, as it's closing and flushing writes to the filesystem over and over.

Comment: That's not always undesirable behavior and it wasn't specified either way. Efficiency was not a consideration either.